# ServletActionContext for struts2 + spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, struts2

I want to change this struts 2 code to spring MVC, does anyone have a clue?

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

I am getting this

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsRequestWrappe@3535
```

while it hits a struts2 web app
and this :

```
 FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@2425]
```

while hitting a spring MVC web app. 
I am a bit confused. 
Any suggestions will help

Comment: do you need to get HttpServletRequest in spring mvc?

Comment: yes, but its giving me FirwallledRequest[..] I don't know what that is.

Comment: Which package the class from?

Comment: Whose controller do you have? Is it spring's then Florescent's answer.

Comment: I don't follow. which class are we talking about?

Comment: yes, its a spring controller. I will try Florescent's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to access the `HttpServletRequest` **request** in spring.

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)
                                RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = attr.getRequest();
```